# make a flask query more efficient

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using this query to get users on bases of status and type of school. Like If I have 5 type of school and 5 type of users I have to query 25 times . Is there any good solution or I am doing it right ?

```
   all_users = (
            session.query(User)
            .join(School)
            .filter(
                School.type == 1,
                User.status == 2,
            )
            .all()
        )
```

Comment: Hey, you'd get a better response over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common situation with a well understood answer: is `in_` on the filter like so:

```
all_users = (
        session.query(User)
        .join(School)
        .filter(
            School.type.in_(my_list_of_school_ids),
            User.status.in_(my_list_of_user_status),
        )
        .all()
    )
```